# What the marginal distribution looks like in an example

Tags: probability

Consider the random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint distribution given by

[image]

We know that the for the random vector $X=(X_{1}, \dots,  X_{n})$, for $j \in \{1, \dots, n \}$

$$P(X_{j}=x)=\sum_{x_{1}}\sum_{x_{2}} \cdots \sum_{x_{n}}P(X_{1}=x_{1}, \dots, X_{n}=x_{n})$$

For the example we have that the marginal of $X$ and $Y$ is

[image]

[image]

But I want to know what the sums look like, e.g.

$$P(X=0)=\sum_{\text{what here?}} P(\text{what here?})$$

I don't see how obvious it is to go from definition to example, any help for this?

Comment: $P(X=0)=\frac18+0+0+0= \frac18$.  $P(X=1)=0 +\frac18 +\frac18=\frac38$. Just add probabilities across the appropriate row (and write in the margin).  Similarly columns for $Y$.